# getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream() always returns null, resource is in application.jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, resources, classpath

I am trying to build and run a desktop application in Java.  It tries to load an image to use as background for the JPanel.

```java
final ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
final InputStream backgroudImageStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("back.jpg");
if (backgroudImageStream != null) {
     final Image backgroundImage = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(backgroudImageStream);
     // ...
} else {
     System.out.println("'back.jpg' resource not found");
}
```

I am using **IntelliJ IDEA** as my IDE.

The 'back.jpg' file is stored in **'resources/'** subdirectory of the project (or to be more exact 'src/main/resources').  This directory is properly marked as Resources Directory, '*.jpg' files are among allowed files (the Resource Patterns option contains only negative patterns - adding explicit `?*.jpg` pattern at beginning didn't help).

I have checked the JAR file, and Application.jar does have 'back.jpg' in main directory of the archive, so the build system correctly adds it to the JAR file.

None of the following combinations I have tried worked:

- `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("back.jpg")`
- `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/back.jpg")`
- `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/src/main/resources/back.jpg")`
- `getClass().getResourceAsStream("back.jpg")`
- `getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/back.jpg")`
- `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/src/main/resources/back.jpg")`

When trying to debug it I have noticed that when trying to locate the resource Java does not include `Application.jar` in the list.  How to change it in IntelliJ IDEA?

I've read numerous questions so far on the topic, but none of them have solved my issue.

---

The IML file for the application includes the following lines:

```xml
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/resources" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/java" isTestSource="true" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target" />
    </content>
```

---

**Solution:** (follows the path in comments to [Svirin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64025596/46058))

The application is build using the `Application` (or to be more exact `Application / Start`) configuration, which can be checked in **Run/Debug Configurations** window (opened using **Edit Configurations** of the build selection button).

If you run it via `Application` you need to add the `resources` dir to the classpath manually.  Go to **Project Settings -> Modules -> choose your module**, there on the **Dependencies** tab click on plus **(+) -> Jars or Directories -> select the dir of the image -> choose as Classes**.

This adds the following lines to the IML file

```xml
    <orderEntry type="module-library">
      <library>
        <CLASSES>
          <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/resources" />
        </CLASSES>
        <JAVADOC />
        <SOURCES />
      </library>
    </orderEntry>
```

Comment: Try `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("back.jpg")`. Do you run it from Intellij?

Comment: @quasimodo00 : Thanks for the suggestion, but it also didn't work. Yes, I am running it from **IntelliJ**.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the directory that contains the image doesn't appear in your `classpath` / `jar` file.

If you want to add the directory to your jar file, go to `Project Structure` (ctrl+alt+shift+s shortcut) -> `Artifacts` tab -> Choose your jar -> click on plus button (`+`) on the `Output Layout` tab -> Choose `Directory Content` -> put the path to the image's dir.

Rebuild your jar and run it again.

Now your jar should contain the image.

Comment: Actually the build Application.jar **does** contain the image (I have checked this). It is just that this jar file is not searched for resources (probably classpath is missing `.`).

Comment: When do you debug the application, do you run it as configured `Jar application` debug configuration or `Application` debug configuration?

Comment: No, it uses `Application` (or to be more exact `Application / Start`) configuration. The `JAR Application` build configuration is not configured. I also wonder why it worked for the author of this app, but it does not work for me.

Comment: If you run it via `Application` you should add this dir to the classpath manually, go to `Project Settings` -> `Modules` -> choose your module -> on the `Dependencies` tab click on plus (+) -> `Jars or Directories` -> select the dir of the image -> choose as classes.

Comment: This action adds your directory to the classpath.
Now you can open console tab in debug mode, expand the command line (the first line) and see your directory in the classpath.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221943/discussion-between-svirin-and-jakub-narebski).